# Custom cropping function in ImageDatagenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, imagedatagenerator

I need to Crop a square shape around a Centre point (x,y) and I try to create my custom function below.

```
from PIL import Image

def Crop_Image(image):
    cropsize = 224
    croplength = cropsize/2
    x = Xcentre
    y = Ycentre
    image_crop = image.crop((x-croplength, y-croplength, x+croplength, y+croplength))
    return image_crop
```

Then passing Crop_Image function in to the Imagedatagenerator.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                             validation_split=0.2,
                             rotation_range=0.2,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             fill_mode='nearest',
                             preprocessing_function=Crop_Image)
```

but in the training process, I have got some error.

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Is this tensorflow or keras? Please add the appropriate framework tag.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, `image` is just another array, why don't you crop it like this:

```
image_crop = image[int(y - croplength):int(y + croplength), int(x - croplength):int(x + croplength)]
```

I added `int` in case `croplength` was not a full number. This is because the indexing of an array should optimally be with full integers

V2.0: with pillow function

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("...")
def Crop_Image(image):
    cropsize = 224
    croplength = int(cropsize/2)
    x = 500
    y = 500
    image_crop = image.crop((x-croplength, y-croplength, x+croplength, y+croplength))
    return image_crop

croppedImage = Crop_Image(image)

plt.imshow(croppedImage)
```

This is working perfectly for me

Comment: Can I ask you one more question, How can I visualize my cropped image from this solution ? I try to visualize by Crop_image(image) but I have got some error "'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: Am not sure what do you mean by your comment, did the cropping work?

Comment: Yes sir I need to check the result from my function.

Comment: And how are you doing that?

Comment: I try to visualize from this code 
image = Image.open('/image')
imgcrop = Crop_Image(image)
plt.imshow(imgcrop)
but I have got some error "'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: Now I see, I didn't notice you were doing this with pillow image. Give me a second

Comment: @whatisthisthisisabook I added an edit, this is working for me

Comment: using the function in the ImageDataGenerator will significantly slow down training because in each epoch each image gets cropped. Crop your images first then feed them to the enerator

Comment: @GerryP also a very important remark